# How to convert Array into json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Dynamically I am getting an `array`.

For example we can consider this following `array`.

```
var sampleArray=[
        "logo",
        "Details",
        "titles"
    ];
```

But I want it something like this.

```
jsonObj={
"poistion1":"logo",
"poistion2":"Details",
"poistion3":"titles"
}
```

Comment: var sampleArray=[
        "logo",
        "Details",
        "titles"
    ];
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(sampleArray, sampleArray.length, String[].class);
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
for(int n = 0; n < mJSONArray.length(); n++)
{ 
    JSONObject object = mJSONArray.getJSONObject(n);
    // do some stuff.... 
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate on array and create object like following

```
var jsonObj = {};
for (var i = 0 ; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
    jsonObj["position" + (i+1)] = sampleArray[i];
}
```

Comment: How about if you want all the `keys` to only read `position`?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty - Not clear. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```js
var jsonObj = {};

var sampleArray = [
    "logo",
    "Details",
    "titles"
];

for (var i = 0, len = sampleArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    jsonObj['position' + (i + 1)] = sampleArray[i];
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty object, then loop over([Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) the array and assign the value

```js
var sampleArray = [
  "logo",
  "Details",
  "titles"
];
var obj = {};
sampleArray.forEach(function(value, idx) {
  obj['position' + (idx + 1)] = value
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
```

Comment: forEach will not be supported in ie lower versions

Comment: @raghavendra there is [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) for that purpose

Comment: asking person don't even know basics about loops. better we can teach them basics loops which will support in standards.

Comment: would you pls explain about  polyfill. does it support in ie6?

Comment: It's 2015, I thought by now we would be beyond asking about support for the officially dead IE6...around only 1.7% of the world uses a browser (old IE) that does not support forEach (ECMAScript 5)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr=[
        "logo",
        "Details",
        "titles"
    ];
var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
      result["position" + (i+1)] = arr[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON Object:

```
var yourObject = [123, "Hello World", {name: "Frankie", age: 15}];
var yourString = JSON.stringify(yourObject); // "[123,"Hello World",{"name":"Frankie","age":15}]"
```

the JSON object has also JSON-to-Object functionality:

`var anotherObject = JSON.parse(yourString);`

Comment: the input is in array, and the required output is in json format with 
`
jsonObj={
"poistion1":"logo",
"poistion2":"Details",
"poistion3":"titles"
}
`
Is your output working and showing the correct output? I dont think so

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var obj = {};
var sampleArray=[
        "logo",
        "Details",
        "titles"
    ];

for(var index in  sampleArray) {
     obj['pos' + index] = sampleArray[index];
   }
```