# How to Convert an Array into Object of key value pair

Tags: javascript

I need to convert an array into object with key values.For Example

```
var Array = [17.3850, 78.4867]
```

I need to convert into Object in this manner

```
var Object = {"lat":17.3850, "lng":78.4867}
```

Comment: this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398984/how-to-convert-array-into-json-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) make an iteration over the array, create an array of Object and finally convert that to an object using [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var key = ['lat', 'lng'];
var array = [17.3850, 78.4867]


var obj = Object.assign({}, ...key.map((e, i) => ({[e]: array[i]})))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map an array with arrays of key/value pairs and create an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var array = [17.3850, 78.4867],
    keys = ['lat', 'lng'],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map((v, i) => [keys[i], v]));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) in JavaScript.

```
class Location {
  constructor(lat, lng) {
   this.lat = lat,
   this.lng = lng
  }
}
var myArray = [17.3850, 78.4867];
var myLocation = new Location(myArray[0], myArray[1]);
myLocation.lat;
myLocation.lng;
```

Instead of `myArray[0]` & `myArray[1]` you can use loop to make it dynamic.